# How to fix this npx create-next-app errror

Tags: typescript, next.js, npx

When i create next app by using `npx create-next-app@latest --typescript` it shows me below error

```
npm ERR! code ENETUNREACH
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ENETUNREACH
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-next-app failed, reason: connect ENETUNREACH 2606:4700::6810:1a23:443

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/krishna/.npm/_logs/2022-12-09T07_50_50_119Z-debug-0.log
```

Please Help How to Fix it ??

I Tried lots of the solutions from internet but couldn't solve it.

Comment: ```yarn create next-app```  You will be asked for the name of your project, and then whether you want to create a TypeScript project: see if this installes your app

Comment: This is not much to go off at all. It's clearly a network issue. You should try running this with a different internet connection or computer on the same network to help troubleshoot what's wrong. Doing it on another day would help too, in case the service is down.

Answer (score -1):

you forgot the `.` or `directory` name

command to install in current directory :

```bash
npx create-next-app@latest . --typescript
```

command to create new directory as `new-directory` then install on them :

```bash
npx create-next-app@latest new-directory --typescript
```

Enjoy Developing !

Answer (score -1):

For me using the git bash terminal solved the problem.
I usually encounter such when using power shell as the terminal.
So just run npx create-next-app in the bash terminal and hopefully that solves it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).